# Arranging columns in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, crosstab

I am currently working on a dataframe from a cross-tab operation.

```
pd.crosstab(data['One'],data['two'], margins=True).apply(lambda r: r/len(data)*100,axis = 1)
```

Columns come out in the following order

```
A   B  C  D  E  All
B   
C   
D   
E
All             100
```

But I want the columns ordered as shown below:

```
A    C  D  B  E All
B
C
D
E
All             100
```

Is there a easy way to organize the columns?
when I use `colnames=['C', 'D','B','E']` it returns an error:

```
'AssertionError: arrays and names must have the same length '
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) or [`reindex_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html) or change order by `subset`:

```
colnames=['C', 'D','B','E']
new_cols = colnames + ['All']

#solution 1 change ordering by reindexing
df1 = df.reindex_axis(new_cols,axis=1)
#solution 2 change ordering by reindexing
df1 = df.reindex(columns=new_cols)
#solution 3 change order by subset
df1 = df[new_cols]

print (df1)
    C   D   B   E    All
0 NaN NaN NaN NaN    NaN
1 NaN NaN NaN NaN    NaN
2 NaN NaN NaN NaN    NaN
3 NaN NaN NaN NaN    NaN
4 NaN NaN NaN NaN  100.0
```

Answer (score 1):

To specify the columns of any dataframe in pandas, just index with a list of the columns in the order you want:

```
columns = ['A', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'E', 'All']
df2 = df.loc[:, columns]
print(df2)
```